# sometimes receiving 'null' on angular/ionic post from service - how to repeat http call?

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework, promise

In my **ionic** app I use a **dataservice** to get data.

On webview (**ionic serve**) the calls are always good. But when testing on ios device I receive null data sometimes (response from error callback).

I dont know why this is happening, it should return data. When I click again the data is received. It happens 1 out of 10 times. So what I want to do is repeat the call untill data is received but I dont know the best approach for this. Here is my code

In state resolve:

```
            resolve: {
                getNewOrders: function (OrderService) {
                    //get new orders
                    OrderService.setNewOrders();
                }
            }
```

In order service:

```
    this.setNewOrders = function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({ template: '<ion-spinner icon="ios"></ion-spinner><p style="margin: 5px 0 0 0;">Getting new orders..</p>'});
    newOrders = false;
    return $http({
        url: api_url + "/get-new-orders",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.data.status == 'success') {
            if (response.data.returnData.length > 0) {
                newOrders = response.data.returnData;
            }
        }
        if (response.status == 'error' || response.status == 'tokenerror') {
            AppService.error(response.status, response.errorMessages);
        }
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        return response.data;
    },
    function(response) { // Error callback
        //alert('ERROR - RELOAD DATA '+response);
        console.log('ERROR - RELOAD DATA '+response);
        setNewOrders(); //<<HERE I WANT TO REPEAT THIS FUNCTION IF NULL DATA IS RECEIVED
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
}
```

so in the error callback I want to reload the http call to get the data.

I dont know why sometimes null is returned, but when repeating the call it gets the data again. So I tought if I just repeat the call unitll data is received its ok.

But I dont know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advised to make a recursive call as you might end up crashing your application. If it not getting data in 1 out 10 times, there must be something wrong, you should fix it. If you insist on using this hack, you should pass integar in params, and then in recalling the method

```
if(count< 5)    
setNewOrders(count + 1);
```

Comment: setNewOrders(); is not executed when i receive the error callback

Comment: if (response.data.returnData.length < 1) {
                if(count< 5)    
setNewOrders(count + 1);
            }

Answer (score 0):

If you return a promise from the error handler the result of that promise will become the result of the original promise.

What that means is that the error handler should return the result of the recursive call:

```
function(response) { // Error callback
    //alert('ERROR - RELOAD DATA '+response);
    console.log('ERROR - RELOAD DATA '+response);
    return setNewOrders();
}
```

and if the next call is successful the `response.data` value will propogate back through the chain of calls.

However Haseeb is correct that you should also use a counter to limit the number of times you can recurse.

Comment: I have tried this, but it does shows the console log and does not repeat the call